# react navigation vs react native navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

what you recommend to use react navigation or react native navigation for large projects? and who has better performance?

I heard a lot of that react navigation has a better performance then I hear react native navigation has better performance. I cant decide which I can use for large project

Comment: I  would suggest `React Navigation` for `expo` managed projects..Managed Workflow..It works like a charm for me and I till date have no issues.

Comment: same case as the above comment